# Tensorflow conflict in ImageAI pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As a `Python 3.9.7` user, I created an environment which has:`tensorflow-gpu==2.6.0`, `keras==2.6.0` and also using `imageai`, however, whenever I run the code, I get the error:

```
File "C:\Users\project-name\.venv\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\YOLOv3\models.py"

ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization'
```

I know that this is related to tensorflow 2.0, as this error gets corrected if I write manually:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
```

But it appears in many other files inside the .venv. How could I possibly solve this error for all the files?

Comment: Why are you installing keras and tensorflow? Just install tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what managed to solve the dependency conflict was - after installing all requirements, I updated `imageai` with:

```
pip install imageai --upgrade
```